# How to access file info programmatically on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

### Setup:

I have a bunch of audio files on my new Mac (Yosemite). When I right click on any file and do "Get Info", it gives me nice detailed info about that song under "More Info" tag, e.g.

[image]

### Objective:

I need to write a program where I can list, something like this for all songs in a directory:

```
Album, Title, Year Recorded
.
.
.
```

### Problem:

I have no idea how to do this. I am totally new to Mac and `Objective-C`/`Swift` (`Objective-C` or `Swift` is what I will have to use to write this program I guess??)

Is there an API where I can access this file info programmatically? And is there any other language which I can use to write this sort of program? Something which I already know, like `Java`, `Python`, etc.?

I don't have any code as of now to show 'What I have tried so far', since I am still searching for the starting point. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to write your app in `Objective-C`, you can also do it using `Swift` :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately I have never used `Swift` either. Updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, the `mdls` command can provide this metadata. You should not try to parse that. Instead, you can use the same APIs that it is built on.

You need to obtain an `NSURL` for a file of interest. Then, you can obtain a dictionary of its metadata attributes like so:

```
MDItemRef item = MDItemCreateWithURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef)url);
NSArray* names = @[ (__bridge NSString*)kMDItemAlbum, /* ... */ ];
NSDictionary* dictionary = CFBridgingRelease(MDItemCopyAttributes(item, (__bridge CFArrayRef)names));
CFRelease(item);
```

Now, `dictionary` contains the desired attributes.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found one way to do this.

Mac does provide a utility called `mdls`, which lists file metadata. So if I do the `mdls` on my about example file, I get this:

```
myuser00m:Hindi myuser$ mdls Pani\ Da\ Rang.mp3 
kMDItemAlbum                    = "Vicky Donor"
kMDItemAlternateNames           = (
    "/Users/myuser/Documents/My Stuff/Music/Hindi/Pani Da Rang.mp3"
)
kMDItemAudioBitRate             = 165000
kMDItemAudioChannelCount        = 2
kMDItemAudioEncodingApplication = "Eac * Lame"
kMDItemAudioSampleRate          = 44100
kMDItemAuthors                  = (
    "Ayushmann Khurrana"
)
kMDItemComposer                 = "Music: Abhishek - Akshay"
kMDItemContentCreationDate      = 2015-06-16 04:42:30 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate  = 2015-06-16 04:42:30 +0000
kMDItemContentType              = "public.mp3"
kMDItemContentTypeTree          = (
    "public.mp3",
    "public.audio",
    "public.audiovisual-content",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemCopyright                = "www.Songs.PK"
kMDItemDateAdded                = 2015-07-26 19:52:49 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName              = "Pani Da Rang"
kMDItemDurationSeconds          = 240.8489795918368
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate      = 2015-06-16 04:42:30 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate           = 2015-06-16 04:42:30 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode            = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags            = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon          = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible              = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden      = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery           = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                  = 0
kMDItemFSName                   = "Pani Da Rang.mp3"
kMDItemFSNodeCount              = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID           = 784317889
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID            = 376797083
kMDItemFSSize                   = 5826388
kMDItemFSTypeCode               = ""
kMDItemKind                     = "MP3 audio"
kMDItemLogicalSize              = 5826388
kMDItemLyricist                 = "www.Songs.PK"
kMDItemMediaTypes               = (
    Sound
)
kMDItemMusicalGenre             = "Bollywood"
kMDItemPhysicalSize             = 5828608
kMDItemRecordingYear            = 2012
kMDItemTitle                    = "Pani Da Rang"
kMDItemTotalBitRate             = 165000
myuser00m:Hindi myuser$
```

Now I need to write some code to parse this and extract fields of interest.

Obviously, it is not that cool solution, but until I find something better, this will do. I will update my answer once I find something better.