# get fileinfo with python on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.6, fileinfo

How do i get to the fileinfo with python on a Mac?
I already tried th os.stat command bit that doesn't seem to get to all the fileinfo that you see when accessing "Get info" when you do right mouse click.

Comment: Some additional info about what i like to do. I want to write a file analyzer mainly for MP3 files that can read the beats per Minut and other fileinfo so i can arrange the files on BPM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access file info programmatically on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641554/how-to-access-file-info-programmatically-on-mac)

Comment: Which file attributes do you think will help to determine the BPM of an MP3 file? You will need to read an analyse the file to do that - `os.stat()` probably won't help much.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Chanda-korat . This will help me on the way.